# Scratched Quartz Countertop

Tags: countertops, quartz

When I was installing a quartz countertop, i had it upside down so I could mount the sink to it.  When I flipped it over, there was a small scratch in it (the quartz was brand new).  I assume there was a screw or something protruding from the cabinet underneath it.  I have seen you can use super glue technique to mask the scratch, but I was hoping there would be something else that would work better.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any adhesive/sealant left from the install you could fill it with?

Mine came with color matched adhesive for the back splash pieces.

Comment: Unfortunately I am used a different material for the back splashes.  The quartz I purchased came with no adhesive.  The polymer compound I used on the underside would certainly not look great on top.  Thanks for the advice though.