# How do I use dust saved from sanding Corian to fix scratches?

Tags: countertops

I recently installed a wet bar with a Corian counter top.  When I sanded it (starting with 200 grit and working up to 2500) i created a bunch of Corian dust.  I had heard that I should save this in case I need to use it for scratches/repairs to the Corian.  Is this accurate?

How can I use this to fix my counter top if I have scratches?  I have roughly 6 oz volume (half of a 12 oz glass -- I know that's not the right way to measure it but I'm not going to weigh it) saved.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your other question asked at the same time: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/97188/scratched-quartz-countertop ?

Comment: That question is about quartz.  This one is about Corian and the other is about Quartz

Comment: Corian is not quartz so this must be a different question. I have used a dual action sander to repair scratches depending on how deep the scratch more aggressive sandpaper then work up to finer grits working a larger area and blend it all back in with a fine wet sandpaper. I have not had any chips or chunks so I am not sure how that would work. If a solid color and the possibility of using the dust I would store in a zip lock bag until you find out for sure.

Comment: I do understand that you want to use the dust. the only way I have repaired other than sanding was to cut a chunk out and replace it. The cuts have to be exact or the line is obvious. I have never used the dust or seen it used.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I saw the quartz question in my feed and thought it sounded really similar. @USER_8675309 must be doing a lot of countertop work this week!

Comment: The idea of using the sanding dust is clever but you'll need an appropriate binder that won't change the color or finish... having a hard time thinking of what that would be.  Unless the repair you need to make is large I think you'd be better off buying the seaming epoxy that is color matched to your Corian to use for repairs.  I've done that and had excellent results.

Comment: Of course, this would only work if the original Corian material was homogenous, i.e. didn't have any internal patterns of different colored materials.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to using wood dust mixed with wood glue to fill in some imperfection on a wood project. You will always see it, but most other folks won't. Kind of depends on the scratch.

If you have a scrap of your corian, put a scratch in it, take the dust, mix with some epoxy fill the scratch and sand flush. See if it works to your satisfaction. Then put away that experience to the day if and when you actually scratch your bar top. And don't forget where you put those corian sandings.

- My assumption is that epoxy will stick to the corian and not pop off.